# Checking if file exists in directory

Tags: php

I have a php script to check whatever files exist or not in a Linux system.

If I delete the file from the directory, the script still gives me true when I call the file_exists function, but the directory is empty.

It seems `scandir function` scan dots in the directory in result giving me file exits statement.

Also, I tried `glob function` I’m getting same result.

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
while(true)
{

  foreach (scandir("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/") as $filename)
  {

    if(file_exists("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/$filename"))
    {
      echo "file exist\n";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "file doesn't exist\n";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: [File stat cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

Comment: Directories are files.  You have just read files/directories and then tested to see if they exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to skip the `.` and `..` results from the `scandir` result:

```
<?php

$files = array_filter(scandir('/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/'), function($item) {
    return $item !== '.' && $item !== '..';
});

foreach ($files as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/$filename"))
    {
        echo "file exist\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file doesn't exist\n";
    }
}
```

By modifying the `array_filter` callback, you can also leave out other files and even subdirectories.

Comment: You need to move the `scandir()` inside of the `while` or the files will never change.

Comment: Indeed, of course. Actually, the `while` loop isn't very useful here is it? I've update my answer to leave it out.

Comment: actually while loop important here. if there's no file you code doesn't give any output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in feature of scandir that will help with this issue. However you could simply do something like this:

```
$filtered_contents = array_diff(scandir("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/"), array('..', '.'));
```

Then use `$filtered_contents` in your `foreach` loop rather than the `scandir` call.

Comment: i used your code but im getting error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /var/www/html/phptest/search8.php on line 6

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /var/www/html/phptest/search8.php on line 6` i tried to remove semicolons im getting an there error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY in /var/www/html/phptest/search8.php on line 6

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY in /var/www/html/phptest/search8.php on line 6
`

Comment: @user3818265 I fixed the bug in my answer, give it another shot

Comment: another error `PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /var/www/html/phptest/search8.php on line 8

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/html/phptest/search8.php on line 8
`

Answer (score 0):

Check using `is_file()` to see if it's a file and not a directory.  Also, `clearstatcache()`:

```
while(true)
{
  clearstatcache();

  foreach(scandir("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/") as $filename)
  {
    if(is_file("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/$filename"))
    {
      echo "file exist\n";
    }
    elseif(!is_dir("/var/log/phplogs/iplogs/$filename"))
    {
      echo "file doesn't exist\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code if file exits it give output `file exist
file doesn't exist
file doesn't exist
file exist
`

Comment: Edited with `!is_dir()`

Comment: i test your code if there's no file it just loop with out any output.

Comment: Yes, and what should it do.  If the file didn't recently exist, then how would it know that it now doesn't?

Comment: no ,if there's no file it should print `echo "file doesn't exist\n";`